# I am getting an error “variableType.itemType is not a function” on pinescript v4

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am getting a pinescript error and tried fixing the code multiple ways like defining dnTrend separately, etc.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Smart Trail with Supertrend and Zone", overlay=true)

// Define the initial stop loss distance and increment
var float stopLossDistance = 0.0
var float stopLossIncrement = 0.01

// Define the trend strength threshold
var float trendStrengthThreshold = 0.5

// Define the Supertrend indicator parameters
len = input(10, minval=1, title="ATR Length")
mult = input(3.0, minval=0.1, maxval=10, title="ATR Multiplier")
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")

// Calculate the Supertrend values
[upTrend, dnTrend] = supertrend(src, len, mult)

// Calculate the trend strength
var float trendStrength = abs(change(close)) / atr(len)

// Check if the trend is strong enough to trail the stop
if trendStrength > trendStrengthThreshold
    // Calculate the new stop loss distance based on the current price
    stopLossDistance := max(stopLossDistance, close - (trendStrength * atr(len)))

// Adjust the stop loss distance based on the trailing stop increment
stopLossDistance := max(stopLossDistance, close - (stopLossIncrement * atr(len)))

// Define the stop loss zone
var float zoneTop = 0.0
var float zoneBottom = 0.0
if upTrend > nz(upTrend[1]) // If we are in an uptrend
    zoneTop := upTrend
    zoneBottom := max(upTrend, stopLossDistance)
else if dnTrend < nz(dnTrend[1]) // If we are in a downtrend
    zoneTop := min(dnTrend, stopLossDistance)
    zoneBottom := dnTrend

// Plot the Supertrend values
plot(upTrend, title="Up Trend", color=color.green, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=2)
plot(dnTrend, title="Down Trend", color=color.red, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=2)

// Plot the stop loss and the stop loss zone
plot(stopLossDistance, title="Stop Loss", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(zoneTop, title="Stop Loss Zone", color=color.new(color.blue, 0), style=plot.style_area, transp=70)
plot(zoneBottom, title="Stop Loss Zone", color=color.new(color.blue, 0), style=plot.style_area, transp=70)
```

I’ve tried declaring dnTrend and upTrend differently, for example separately or switching the location of where it is declared and more.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way you call supertrend where the error is.

The supertrend function accept 2 arguments only.

You should write :

```
[upTrend, dnTrend] = supertrend(mult, len)
```